# Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different

Tags: xetex, pgfplots, input, characters

I'm trying out [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgflots) with `gnuplot` to generate the data.  This works by having pgfplots write some stuff to an external file, run gnuplot on the file, and then use the generated data to plot the graph.

The problem I'm having is that I get different behaviour under `xelatex` as `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.  In `xelatex`, the data file is littered with `^^I` whereas in the other two formats these are tabs.  It *appears* that the code `^^I` is getting stored as a macro which then gets written out to the file, so possibly there's something funny going on with the `^^I` syntax: `xelatex` is reading it literally.  Indeed, when I do `\show\pgfplots@TAB` (the macro in question) then for `pdflatex` and `lualatex` then I get a literal tab whereas for `xelatex` I get `^^I`.

So how do I get a tab in `xelatex`?  And why isn't `\gdef\pgfplots@TAB{^^I}` working?

(The previous line in the code, by the way, is `` \catcode`\^^I=12 `` - I don't know if that has anything to do with it.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In TeX Live, the formats for pdf(la)tex and lua(la)tex are built loading the tcx translation file `cp227.tcx` that makes `^^I` "printable". This means that a category code 12 `^^I` is written out as a real tab character.

On the other hand, xetex ignores tcx translation requests and behaves, in this respect, like Knuth's TeX (but it writes UTF-8, of course).

The same problem arises with `\begin{frame}[fragile]` with `beamer`, because the contents of the environment is written to a temporary file, or with `\verbatimwrite` and similar commands; also the `filecontents` environment is probably affected.

A solution may be to call xetex with the command line option `-8bit`, but I don't know if this has other side effects.

Comment: Miktex uses cp227.tcx too. And while the --8bit-option is actually not mentioned in the documentation it nevertheless works with xe(la)tex. As far as I can see the chars > ASCII 32 are printable anyway in xetex, so it will affect only (some or all) ASCII 0-32.

Comment: The `-8bit` option certainly makes it work.  I'll keep an eye out for side effects.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to ensure a correct behavior directly in the source code? I could patch pgfplots to do the right thing...

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I just got bitten by this again - I'd even forgotten that I'd asked this question! - at the least, it might be worth mentioning this in the manual at various relevant places (I only looked at the `contour gnuplot` part so somewhere there would be great).

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the hint. I could do that... but honestly: I fear that such a small hint will be lost in 400 pages of documentation. I would rather have some meaningful error message like "Aargh unsupported use -8bit bla blubb". Perhaps I could write out a file, reread it and check if it contains three chars instead of one ;-)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger How about a "Known limitations" section in the manual?  Also you could test for `xelatex` and print a warning "You're using xelatex.  If things don't appear how you expect, try running with the -8bit option."

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I've asked a follow-up question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52316/86 I suspect the answer is "no", but we can but hope!

Comment: me I do: sed -i -e "s/pdflatex/xelatex/g"  -e "s/\^\^I/\t/g" \jobname.makefile

Comment: I enter the same problem when I use `mpgraphics` package and run it with `xelatex` engin, which then the `*.mp` code generated by `mpgraphics` will display `Tab` as `^^I`. The solution is exactly add `-8bit`: `xelatex -8bit -shell-escape -synctex=1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*`.

Comment: @user19832 Not using tabs is easier, though. `;-)` Do you really need `-src-specials`?

Comment: @egreg I thought it is essential to make forward searching to work?

Comment: @user19832 It's an outdated method; SyncTeX is much better.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it seems safe to remove the option `-src-specials` in my xelatex compile command.