# Externalising TikZ pictures using XeTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex, tikz-external

I'm trying to use TikZ's *external*  library with XeTeX, for [example](http://pastebin.com/5TZLCWRx), and I'm running into some issues. Having set

```
external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
    -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}
```

(EDIT: as an answer points out I had accidentaly used ``` ``...'' ``` instead of `"..."` here) while using the default `mode=convert with system call` XeTeX just dies with the following error

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname ``xetexpics
/externalTest-figure0'' ``\def\tikzexternalrealjob{externalTest}\input{externalTest}''' did NOT result in a usab
le output file 'xetexpics/externalTest-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you 
have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18'
or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'xetexpics/externalT
est-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

(EDIT: This was due to only restructed write18 being enabled, see comment)

without producing the log file. Changing to `mode=list and make` it produces an [incorrect makefile](http://pastebin.com/6iVSvWWe) where all tabs have been replaced by `^^I` and without properly escaped backslashes. [Fixing these errors](http://pastebin.com/FqVuHieF) and running make seems to indicate success, but the generated images are empty. The only warning or error I can seem to find in the log is

```
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
```

Has anyone had any success with using *external* with XeTeX, and does anyone have any suggestions on how to make it work?

I'm using `XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2012/dev/Arch Linux)`, `pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10` and `tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10` according to the log.

Comment: The info message about `\expanded` is normal and surely has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: If the original system call did not produce any .log file for the individual images, it may have failed to run the system call. For pdftex, this usually produces some kind of log warning of sort "write 18 call has been forbidden" in the .log file of the main file. Perhaps the shell-escape is inactive.

Comment: Could you try to convert one of the image `.pdf`s to `.ps` and view them in `gv`? Perhaps the picture's dimensions are set incorrectly by tikz - and as far as I know, pdf will ALWAYS remove picture parts outside of the bounding box whereas `.ps` files will display them. If the bounding box turns out to be wrong, you have found a bug in tikz (probably a bug of the pgf basic layer externalization).

Comment: I realised that I had only restricted write18 enabled, and that xelatex wasn't part of the enabled programs (for good reasons). Having changed this I can compile with `convert with system call`. Converting the pdf to a ps with `pdf2ps` still produces an empty document.

Comment: I have just tried to compile an example with my local xelatex. I fear it is outdated (version `This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=xelatex 2011.7.30)`), but at least the produced figure worked perfectly. Maybe I really need to upgrade to a more recent texlive ;)  . Anyway, perhaps the pgf support for xetex is broken on your system. On mine, the _figures_ `.log` file contains something like `Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-xetex.def ...
(...systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
 pgfsys-xetex.def 2010/02/16  (rcs-revision 1.3)`

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I guess it might just be a bug in my version then (of either XeTeX or TikZ).

Answer (score 10):

The problem of writing "incorrectly" the tab is known (see [Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/tabs-in-output-file-written-by-xelatex-and-pdflatex-are-different))

The "solution" is to call

```
xelatex -8bit -shell-escape
```

but this may have adverse effects on the writing of aux files.

Pay attention on how you write:

```
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

should have real double quotes.

Comment: Very true, that's what I get for just copy-pasting into emacs :) Also -8bit does solve the tab issue, but it still doesn't seem to produce the picture.

Comment: Where should these commands be added? I am using TexShop on Mac OS X.

Comment: @WayneTsai You should open `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/XeLaTeX.engine` (with any text editor, including TeXShop) and add `-8bit -shell-escape` to the last line, after `xelatex`.

Comment: @WayneTsai It's actually better if you duplicate `XeLaTeX.engine` into, say, `XeLaTeX-shell.engine` and do the above modification to the duplicate file; so long as it has `.engine` extension and lives in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`, it will appear in the drop down menu near to the Typeset button.