# Using minted and tabs

Tags: xetex, minted

I just started using the `minted` package. When I insert tabs as indentation, it gives me a bunch of characters instead:

[image]

However, when I copy the example from the [documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) it seems to work fine. I tried experimenting with the `obeytabs` and `showtabs` options but I can't get rid of the characters. I'm using `xelatex` with TexLive 2011 in TexShop. All files are up to date.

Here's a MWE (please note as pointed out in the comments that the indentation in the code is supposed to be tabs and not spaces):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{python}{linenos}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{python}
def all(iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        if not i:
            return False
    return True
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: I noticed something strange: When I change the typesetting engine back to `pdflatex`, it seems to be working, but then I can't load the `fontspec` package. So I guess this is related to `xelatex`?

I'm using `xelatex --file-line-error --shell-escape --synctex=1`

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me; are you compiling with `xelatex -shell-escape myfile.tex`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would give me an error. My TexShop Engine says: `xelatex --file-line-error --shell-escape --synctex=1`

Comment: Works for me with an up-to-date TL2011. Could you add the output that `\listfiles` produces in your log, so we can see file versions?

Comment: I updated the files today, but here you go: http://pastebin.com/MHV57LbY

Comment: Please include all your code in your question on here so people can see it immediately without having to go to some external site.

Comment: When I copy/paste your MWE, I get spaces for indentation, instead of tabs.  I'm not sure if it's possible to put literal tab characters into HTML, so you should probably link to a file or remind people to change the spaces to tabs before running the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a manifestation of the problem discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/tabs-in-output-file-written-by-xelatex-and-pdflatex-are-different) – xe(la)tex has a bug that makes it write tabs incorrectly.  The fix discussed there is to pass the `-8bit` command-line option to `xelatex`.  It is said (by someone who seems pretty knowledgeable) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32400/3087) that "this may have adverse effects on the writing of aux files," but I am not sure what those may be.

Comment: It works using the -8bit option. What does it do?