# How can I preserve all whitespace in an environment?

Tags: xetex, indentation, verbatim

I'm typesetting literate programs; they look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\Symbola}{Symbola}
\newfontfamily{\UbuntuMono}{Ubuntu Mono}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\S}{\Symbola}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{code}{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\UbuntuMono}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
  (fold\_left (\S{λ} x \textcolor{red}{y}.  x \S{⊕} \textcolor{red}{y})\\
             (a \S{∷} b \S{∷} c \S{∷} d \S{∷} nil))
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

How can I make sure that the `code` environment preserves all whitespaces? In particular, that whitespaces should be in the generated PDF too: that is, copy-pasting from the PDF should copy the whitespaces as well.

Here are a few attempts:

- Use `\hspace{}`: not very nice when looking at the sources, and spaces can't be copied from resulting PDF.
- Replace all spaces by `~`, and add `\-` for beginning-of-line spaces. Sources become ugly (not a show-stopper), but spaces still can't be copied.
- Use `\catcode32=12` in definition of `code`. This works fine alignment-wise, it looks perfect… but spaces still can't be copied.
- Using the `listings` package: would be great, but it dies on Unicode, and I'm tired of the `literate`-based workarounds
- Using the `fancyvrb` package: Has an `escapechar` property that could be promising, and line breaks being significant in the source are not a deal-breaker, but it seems heavyweight (?). Ideally, I'd like to be able to use this environment inline, too.

**What magic do I need to make my environment respect all spaces, and make them copy-pastable from the PDF?**

Comment: have you tried [`minted` (example Q here -- might be relevant as it's XeTeX)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/using-minted-and-tabs).  I'm not an expert as I use `pdflatex`+`listings` for exactly what you want minus the unicode but I've heard good thigns about it.

Comment: @ChrisH: Minted definitely doesn't work for me; I can't rely on a Python installation being available, and I don't need any automatic syntax highlighting.

Comment: Producing white space in the document might be doable (i.e., `\newenvironment{code}{\obeyspaces\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\UbuntuMono}{}` and then using `\\\mbox{}` instead of `\\ `), but the copy/paste in the PDF is much more problematic, I think.  If I recall, PDF doesn't use spaces in the traditional sense, but individually moves the "cursor" before placing each word.  The "moving the cursor" part is not made equivalent to some number of blank spaces.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the pointer to `obeyspaces`!

Comment: Regarding whitespaces: I'm sure it can be done: iI print this page to PDF in chromium, copy pasting the "code" part of my post respects spaces, and I can select them individually.

Comment: You are welcome.  There is still the problem though that leading spaces on a line are not uncovered by `\obeyspaces`.  The typical way that is handled is to put a non-printing something at the beginning of the line, such as `\mbox{}`, so that subsequent spaces may be recognized and processed accordingly.  However, the copy/paste issue of PDF spaces persists, in any event.  Best wishes!

Answer (score 4):

**ANSWER REVISITED**

When it was pointed out to me that, except in computer modern, my original answer was no different that what the OP was able to achieve with  `\catcode32=12`, I took another look at things.  I came up with a wholly satisfactory answer when using pdflatex, and a less satisfying one for xelatex.  In both cases, they start by making the space an active character and then redefining it to print a particular character in white.

EDITED to make the space the proper width.

-----*pdflatex*

Here I use package `palatino` just to make sure I am not relying on some special aspect of computer modern.  Here, the "particular character" I print for a space, in white, is the visible space from the `lmodern` font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{palatino}
\newsavebox\spacewd
\savebox\spacewd{\texttt{ }}
\newenvironment{code}{\par\catcode32=\active \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\ttfamily}{\par}
{
\catcode32=\active %
\gdef {\makebox[\wd\spacewd][l]{%
\textcolor{white}{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont\large\smash{\char32}}}}% 
}
\begin{document}
\noindent xyz
\begin{code}
  (fold\_left (\S{λ} x \textcolor{red}{y}.  x \S{⊕} \textcolor{red}{y})\\
             (a \S{∷} b \S{∷} c \S{∷} d \S{∷} nil))
\end{code}
\noindent this is
  a
    test to make    sure all 
      is back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image]

The PDF copy/paste performs as follows:

[image]

which is exactly what is desired.

-----*xelatex*

Here I use `libertine` font.  The only quirk here is that `\textvisiblespace` takes up less horizontal width than a `\ttfamily` space and so to avoid the PDF from interpreting the spaced out `\textvisiblespace`s as a double space, I made the `\textvisiblespace` that gets inserted both `\large` and `\smash`ed to avoid PDF interpreting it as an extra gap.  Further, I make the `\makebox` left aligned, so that the large white `\textvisiblespace` didn't overwrite the prior character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec,libertine}
\newsavebox\spacewd
\savebox\spacewd{\texttt{ }}
\newenvironment{code}{\par\catcode32=\active \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\ttfamily}{\par}
{
\catcode32=\active %
\gdef {\makebox[\wd\spacewd][l]{\textcolor{white}{\large\smash{\textvisiblespace}}}}% 
}

\begin{document}
\noindent xyz
\begin{code}
  (fold\_left (\S{λ} x \textcolor{red}{y}.  x \S{⊕} \textcolor{red}{y})\\
             (a \S{∷} b \S{∷} c \S{∷} d \S{∷} nil))
\end{code}
\noindent this is
  a
    test to make    sure all 
      is back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image]

The resulting copy/paste from the PDF is

[image]

in which another character is substituted for the space, in this case I had designated `\textvisiblespace`.  I verified that my TeXworks editor can replace the invisible space character with a real space on a global basis.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This answer is based on my year-old suggestion of using `\obeyspaces` in the `code` environment to preserve blank spaces.  However, as noted in the comments, it does not detect leading spaces on a line.

To remedy that, I used egreg's answer at [Using end-of-line delimiter in plain Tex macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125549/using-end-of-line-delimiter-in-plain-tex-macro).  With it,  I am able to intercept the end of line (EOL) inside the `code` environment.  I use this fact to place a `\mbox{}` at the beginning of each new line inside `code`, so that the `\obeyspaces` can detect the leading blank spaces of each subsequent line.

The hard part (for me) was restoring the EOL to its rightful place upon exiting `code`.  I did that with a test on a flag macro `\endthis`, which gets changed from `F` to `T` during the exit code from `code`.

**However, the underlying problem of copy/paste of whitespace from the PDF remains.**

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily{\Symbola}{Symbola}
%\newfontfamily{\UbuntuMono}{Ubuntu Mono}
%\DeclareTextFontCommand{\S}{\Symbola}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{code}
{\par\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\obeyspaces\ttfamily\gdef\endthis{F}\mymacro}
{\gdef\endthis{T}\par}

\def\mymacro{%
  \if\endthis T\def\next{}\else\def\next{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \xmymacro}\fi\next}
{\catcode`\^^M=12 %
 \gdef\xmymacro#1^^M{\mbox{}#1\endgroup\mymacro}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent xyz
\begin{code}
  (fold\_left (\S{λ} x \textcolor{red}{y}.  x \S{⊕} \textcolor{red}{y})\\
             (a \S{∷} b \S{∷} c \S{∷} d \S{∷} nil))
\end{code}
\noindent this is
  a
    test to make    sure all 
      is back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image]

The use of `\catcode32=12`, which the OP had mentioned, in the definition of `code` is similar, but it produces "visual spaces"

[image]

Comment: If you don't need to solve the issue of spaces not being copyable from the PDF, isn't `\catcode32=12` a much simpler solution? The OP wrote “Use `\catcode32=12` in definition of `code`. This works fine alignment-wise, it looks perfect… but spaces still can't be copied.” How is this better? Can you compare the merits of this solution and that one?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR See addendum to my answer.

Comment: The visible spaces are an idiosyncrasy of Computer Modern; the problem isn't present with the OP's chosen font (Ubuntu Mono).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR In that case, it would appear my solution is a sophisticated redundancy.

Comment: :-) It's instructive nevertheless. Too bad the PDF-copy problem (which keeps coming up) doesn't have a great solution.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Please see my revision