# Tikz external makefile error

Tags: xetex, tikz-external, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Externalising TikZ pictures using XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32397/externalising-tikz-pictures-using-xetex)

I'm having some trouble getting the externalize tikz library working correctly with xetex. In "list and make" mode, the tabs in the makefile are replaced by "^^I". It works fine for pdflatex. Is there a command that I messed up?

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=., mode=list and make]
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} %
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,1); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the resulting makefile:

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=$(shell cat minimal.figlist)
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
^^I@echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
^^Itouch $@ # will be filled later.

.minimal-figure0.pdf: 
^^Ixelatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname ".minimal-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{minimal}\input{minimal}"
```