# Does tex know its own command line arguments?

Tags: tex-core, options

Is it possible to test within the document what commandline arguments were passed to tex?  The particular case that prompts this is the question [Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14771/86) where it would be useful to know if the `-8bit` argument has been passed to tex and issue a warning if not.  That is, if `pgfplots` could contain the code:

```
\ifxetex
 \ifarg{8bit}
 \else
  \pkgwarning{You're using xe(la)tex without the -8bit argument.  Some external files might go wrong.  If things don't work as you expect, try using the -8bit argument.}
 \fi
\fi
```

then it might make it easier to spot when the situation of the linked question occurs.

(A year after asking the above question, it happened to me again and it took me some time to realise what the problem was and find the solution, even though it had been me who found it last time!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is "not directly".

One can define such a test:

```
\input catchfile.sty
\newif\ifeightbit
\begingroup
  \immediate\openout15=tab.tst
  \catcode`\^^I=12
  \immediate\write15{^^I}
  \immediate\closeout15
  \CatchFileDef\atab{tab.tst}{\catcode`\^=12 \catcode`I=12 }
  \edef\btab{\string^\string^\string I }
  \ifx\atab\btab
    \global\eightbitfalse
  \else
    \global\eightbittrue
  \fi
\endgroup
\show\ifeightbit
```

With `xetex test` (`test.tex` is the file name) we'll get `\iffalse` while with `xetex -8bit test` we'll get `\iftrue`.

It seems to be impossible to do this without writing a file, because `\scantokens` avoids the "translation" via the `xchr` tables. So while we can catch the three distinct characters when reading back the file, if written without the `-8bit` option, we can't do it with `\scantokens`.

Comment: I'm guessing from this that the answer to the general question is "No".

Comment: You're guessing right. :)

Comment: Fancy adding that to your answer?  It *was* the actual question, after all!

Answer (score 1):

With `--shell-escape`:

> (because of some permission issue this does not work on Overleaf, but otherwise should work on most POSIX systems)
>
> ```
> \ExplSyntaxOn
> \sys_get_shell:nnN {ps~-o~args=~-p~$(ps~-o~ppid=~-p~$$)} {\cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab} \l_data_tl
> \ExplSyntaxOff
> ```

Quoted from my other answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621510/250119.

Then you need to parse the arguments somehow -- but be warned that parsing the arguments correctly is really difficult.
A simple way is

```
\str_if_in:VnTF \l_data_tl {-8} {
  \typeout{>> probably~8bit}
} {
  \typeout{>> not~8bit}
}
```

but it's not foolproof, I run this simple bash file:

```bash
g(){
    echo "========" "$@"
    "$@" </dev/null | grep '>>\|!'
}
f(){
    g pdflatex --shell-escape "$@"
    g xelatex --shell-escape "$@"
}

mkdir -p -- --8bit a "a a"  # create auxiliary directories named literally "--8bit" and "a" and "a a"
ln -rsf a.tex "a --8bit b.tex"  # link "a.tex" -> a file literally named "a --8bit b.tex"
ln -rsf a.tex "b.tex"

# ======== these 3 cases return false:
f  a.tex
f  --output-di a "a --8bit b.tex"
f  --output-di --8bit a.tex
# ======== these 7 cases return true:
f  --output-di "a a" --8bit b.tex
f  -8bit a.tex
f  -8b a.tex
f  --8bit a.tex
f  --8bi a.tex
f  --8b a.tex
f  --8 a.tex
f  -8 a.tex
```

with `a.tex` contains:

```
% ======== copy from egreg's test ========
\input catchfile.sty
\newif\ifeightbit
\begingroup
  \immediate\openout15=tab.tst
  \catcode`\^^?=12
  \immediate\write15{^^?}
  \immediate\closeout15
  \CatchFileDef\atab{tab.tst}{\catcode`\^=12 \catcode`?=12 }
  \edef\btab{\string^\string^\string ? }
  \ifx\atab\btab
    \global\eightbitfalse
  \else
    \global\eightbittrue
  \fi
\endgroup




\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_in:nnTF {V}
\sys_get_shell:nnN {ps~-o~args=~-p~$(ps~-o~ppid=~-p~$$)} {\cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab} \l_data_tl
\typeout{>> \l_data_tl}

\str_if_in:VnTF \l_data_tl {-8} {
  \typeout{>> probably~8bit}
} {
  \typeout{>> not~8bit}
}

\typeout{>> ifeightbit=\meaning\ifeightbit}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

As you can see, the simple test outputs "probably 8bit" for the last 2 cases of the first block
even though it isn't 8bit.

In particular, the 2nd and 4nd case makes the output **identical** with the provided command-line argument
(you can fix this by not using `ps -o args` but I'm not sure how...)

---

With LuaLaTeX there's the `arg` table, but it looks like you'll still have to manually parse it:

```
\directlua{for _, v in ipairs(arg) do print(v) end}
\stop
```

From the other question in [In Luatex, how to know effective output directory?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388326/250119).

But... in this specific case LuaTeX always ignore `--8bit` argument anyway:

[image: luatex documentation]

Comment: That is all above my head. But: Might it be possible to run a macro that produces different results, in the two cases, but does not print anything or throw an error? Then the logic could be forked, based on the result. No shell escape. I do something similar with `lualatex` and `fontspec`. After main font is set, I use `\sbox0` with some text that has high and low points (such as Aacute and jyg). Then I measure `\ht0` and `\dp0` and fork, based on the length. Differentiates between "big glyph" fonts and "small glyph" fonts. I can even re-define font size and baselineskip.

Comment: @rallg If you have some good idea why don't you post an answer? (I don't.)

Comment: Sadly, I do not have any idea that addresses the question (as asked). My above comment is very user-specific (me). I just happen to be an advocate of lualatex and fontspec.